# change date format while displaying date column from database Yii

Tags: php, yii

while displaying  data from database in my yii webapp i want to change the date format of my date column from yyyy-mm-dd  to dd-mm-yyyy ..

code in my view for date of birth column.

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('Date Of Birth')); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->dob); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
 Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime(
                CDateTimeParser::parse(
                    $data->dob, 
                    'dd-mm-yyyy'
                ),
                'short',null
            );
```

Ref: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/183/using-international-dates/

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`DateTime`**](https://www.php.net/DateTime)

- Create a DateTime object with the value you have now
- Reformat the object to the desired format.

```
<?php

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $data->dob);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

https://eval.in/205827

Comment: You're welcome - However, as you're using Yii, it may be worthwhile using @KrishR answer. (I've never used Yii, so...)

Comment: Ah okay :) I'm glad I gave an alternative solution then